# How do I create a yml file to run CI/CD on github for java maven project

Tags: java, maven, junit, github-actions, cicd

I have been trying to create a github workflow to run my junit test cases when there is a push to my repository but when I try doing it the "actions" tab says it was successful but if I look into the logger it says it ran zero tests. can someone help me with the yml file that goes into .github -> .workflows -> XXXXX.yml

Below are my Java files

**RobotMotion.Java**

```
package com.github.DaBrogrammer;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RobotMotion {
    private static int[][] floor;
    private static int posX;
    private static int posY;
    private static boolean penDown;
    private static Direction direction;

    public static Object[] getFloor() {
        return floor;
    }

    public static int getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }

    public static int getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }

    public static boolean isPenDown() {
        return penDown;
    }
    
    public static void setPen(boolean setting) {
        penDown = setting;
    }

    public static Direction getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    enum Direction {
        NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean running = true;

        while (running) {
            System.out.print("Enter command: ");
            String command = scanner.nextLine();

            if (command.length() > 0) {
                char commandChar = Character.toLowerCase(command.charAt(0));
                String commandArgs = command.length() > 1 ? command.substring(2) : "";

                switch (commandChar) {
                    case 'i' -> {
                        int n = Integer.parseInt(commandArgs);
                        initializeSystem(n);
                    }
                    case 'c' -> printCurrentPosition();
                    case 'd' -> setPen(true);
                    case 'u' -> setPen(false);
                    case 'r' -> turnRight();
                    case 'l' -> turnLeft();
                    case 'm' -> {
                        int spaces = Integer.parseInt(commandArgs);
                        move(spaces);
                    }
                    case 'p' -> printFloor();
                    case 'q' -> running = false;
                    default -> System.out.println("Invalid command!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void initializeSystem(int n) {
        floor = new int[n][n];
        for (int[] row : floor) {
            Arrays.fill(row, 0);
        }
        posX = 0;
        posY = 0;
        penDown = false;
        direction = Direction.NORTH;
    }

    static void printCurrentPosition() {
        System.out.printf("Position: %d, %d - Pen: %s - Facing: %s\n",
                posX, posY, penDown ? "down" : "up", direction.toString().toLowerCase());
    }

    static void turnRight() {
        switch (direction) {
            case NORTH -> direction = Direction.EAST;
            case EAST -> direction = Direction.SOUTH;
            case SOUTH -> direction = Direction.WEST;
            case WEST -> direction = Direction.NORTH;
        }
    }

    static void turnLeft() {
        switch (direction) {
            case NORTH -> direction = Direction.WEST;
            case EAST -> direction = Direction.NORTH;
            case SOUTH -> direction = Direction.EAST;
            case WEST -> direction = Direction.SOUTH;
        }
    }

    static void move(int spaces) {

        if (penDown) {
            floor[posX][posY] = 1; // Mark the initial position with "*" if pen is down
        }

        switch (direction) {
            case NORTH -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
                    if (posY < floor.length - 1) {
                        posY++;
                        if (penDown) {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            case EAST -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
                    if (posX < floor.length - 1) {
                        posX++;
                        if (penDown) {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            case SOUTH -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
                    if (posY > 0) {
                        posY--;
                        if (penDown) {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            case WEST -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
                    if (posX > 0) {
                        posX--;
                        if (penDown) {
                            floor[posX][posY] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void printFloor() {
        int size = floor.length;

        // Print the top border
        System.out.print("  +");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print("--");
        }
        System.out.println("+");

        // Print the rows
        for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(j + " |"); // Print the row number

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (i == posX && j == posY) {
                    System.out.print(penDown ? "* " : "  "); // Check pen state before printing
                } else {
                    System.out.print(floor[i][j] == 1 ? "* " : "  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }

        // Print the bottom border
        System.out.print("  +");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print("--");
        }
        System.out.println("+");

        // Print the column numbers
        System.out.print("   ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

**RobotMotionTest.java**

```
package com.github.DaBrogrammer;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class RobotMotionTest {
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outputStream));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInitializeSystem() {
        RobotMotion.initializeSystem(3);

        int[][] expectedFloor = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
        Assertions.assertArrayEquals(expectedFloor, RobotMotion.getFloor());

        Assertions.assertEquals(0, RobotMotion.getPosX());
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, RobotMotion.getPosY());

        Assertions.assertFalse(RobotMotion.isPenDown());

        Assertions.assertEquals(RobotMotion.Direction.NORTH, RobotMotion.getDirection());
    }

    @Test
    public void testTurnRight() {
        RobotMotion.initializeSystem(3);

        RobotMotion.turnRight();
        Assertions.assertEquals(RobotMotion.Direction.EAST, RobotMotion.getDirection());

        RobotMotion.turnRight();
        Assertions.assertEquals(RobotMotion.Direction.SOUTH, RobotMotion.getDirection());

        RobotMotion.turnRight();
        Assertions.assertEquals(RobotMotion.Direction.WEST, RobotMotion.getDirection());

        RobotMotion.turnRight();
        Assertions.assertEquals(RobotMotion.Direction.NORTH, RobotMotion.getDirection());
    }

    @Test
    public void testTurnLeft() {
        RobotMotion.initializeSystem(3);

        RobotMotion.turnLeft();
        Assertions.assertEquals(RobotMotion.Direction.WEST, RobotMotion.getDirection());

        RobotMotion.turnLeft();
        Assertions.assertEquals(RobotMotion.Direction.SOUTH, RobotMotion.getDirection());

        RobotMotion.turnLeft();
        Assertions.assertEquals(RobotMotion.Direction.EAST, RobotMotion.getDirection());

        RobotMotion.turnLeft();
        Assertions.assertEquals(RobotMotion.Direction.NORTH, RobotMotion.getDirection());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSetPenDown() {
        RobotMotion.initializeSystem(3);
        RobotMotion.setPen(true);
        Assertions.assertTrue(RobotMotion.isPenDown());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSetPenUp() {
        RobotMotion.initializeSystem(3);
        Assertions.assertFalse(RobotMotion.isPenDown());
        RobotMotion.setPen(false);
        Assertions.assertFalse(RobotMotion.isPenDown());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMove() {
        RobotMotion.initializeSystem(3);
        
        RobotMotion.setPen(true); // must set pen down in order to draw
        RobotMotion.move(2);
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, RobotMotion.getPosX());
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, RobotMotion.getPosY());
        //Assertions.assertFalse(RobotMotion.isPenDown());

        RobotMotion.turnRight();
        RobotMotion.move(1);
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, RobotMotion.getPosX());
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, RobotMotion.getPosY());
        //Assertions.assertFalse(RobotMotion.isPenDown());
    }

    @Test
    public void testPrintCurrentPosition() {
        RobotMotion.initializeSystem(3);

        RobotMotion.printCurrentPosition();
        Assertions.assertEquals("Position: 0, 0 - Pen: up - Facing: north\n", outputStream.toString());
        
        outputStream.reset();
        RobotMotion.setPen(true); // must set pen down in order to draw
        RobotMotion.turnRight();
        RobotMotion.move(2);
        RobotMotion.printCurrentPosition();
        Assertions.assertEquals("Position: 2, 0 - Pen: down - Facing: east\n", outputStream.toString());
        
        outputStream.reset();
        RobotMotion.turnLeft();
        RobotMotion.move(1);
        RobotMotion.printCurrentPosition();
        Assertions.assertEquals("Position: 2, 1 - Pen: down - Facing: north\n", outputStream.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testPrintFloor() {
        RobotMotion.initializeSystem(3);

        RobotMotion.move(2);
        RobotMotion.turnRight();
        RobotMotion.move(1);

        outputStream.reset();
        RobotMotion.printFloor();

        String expectedOutput = "  +------+" + System.lineSeparator() +
                "2 |      |" + System.lineSeparator() +
                "1 |      |" + System.lineSeparator() +
                "0 |      |" + System.lineSeparator() +
                "  +------+" + System.lineSeparator() +
                "   0 1 2 " + System.lineSeparator();

        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedOutput, outputStream.toString());
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.DaBrogrammer</groupId>
    <artifactId>RobotMotion</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- junit 5, unit test -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-runner -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here is a screenshot of my directory:

[My code directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p07N.png)

Comment: Do you have a link to your project? Why have you defined the platform runner as a dependency? Which Maven version do you use ? Have you defined the maven-surefire-plugin version? I doubt you have? please check (https://www.youtube.com/@khmarbaise) also https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/blob/main/episode-2/pom.xml

Comment: Junit4 and junit5 works differently. You need to be certain you invoke it the same way as you do locally.

Comment: Please include your workflow along with the run logs in your question.